# Updating state from an array with react useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Currently I'm using a state with key values. I'm updating that state from an array by looping over the array and setting state each loop. All this logic is happening from a function that is called from a onChange event from a text input.

The expected output from typing only the letter "c" in the text box is that two parameters in the state get changed. Each Key that starts with "c" has a value of false that should be switched to true.

The actual output is only one key value is changed

**The array:**

```
const unitList = [
    "cru",
    "co",
    "vr",
    "lr",
    "sr",
    "tg",
    "tra",
    "dh",
    "pl",
    "kh",
    "nh",
  ];
```

**State:**

```
const [optionList, setOptionList] = useState({
    cru: false,
    co: false,
    vr: false,
    lr: false,
    sr: false,
    tg: false,
    tra: false,
    dh: false,
    pl: false,
    kh: false,
    nh: false,
  });
```

**User types in input box that onChange triggers this function function**

```
const onSearchType = (e) => {
    var inputText = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    unitList.forEach((unit, index) => {
      if (unit.substring(0, inputText.length).toUpperCase() === inputText)
        setOptionList({ ...optionList, [unit]: true });
    });
  };
```

**If user types the letter c in the textbox I would expect the state value to return all items that start with c to be true so state would look like this**

```
cru: true,
co: true,
vr: false,
lr: false,
sr: false,
tg: false,
tra: false,
dh: false,
pla: false,
kh: false,
nh: false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `setOptionList({ ...optionList, [unit]: true });` this call is async.  it would keeps overwriting the `optionList`. So if you set one unit to true, the next call will set every other unit back to its initial value due to the {...optionList} in the call.

To fix use a clone object of optionList and update that instead

`const clone = { ...optionList };`

```
 const onSearchType = (e) => {
    var inputText = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    const clone = { ...optionList };
    unitList.forEach((unit, index) => {
      if (unit.substring(0, inputText.length).toUpperCase() === inputText)
        clone[unit] = true;
    });
    setOptionList(clone);
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-proskuriakova-6x4bxn?file=/src/App.js:0-975